# Deploy a SQL Server Analysis Services Project using PowerShell -

Tags: powershell, deployment, ssas

I used [this](https://vaniecastro.com/2014/06/04/deploy-a-sql-server-analysis-services-project-using-powershell/) to deploy SSAS project. I am getting error 'Cannot bind argument to parameter "Path" because it is null'. Am getting this when assigning value to $xmla.

Comment: Hi, please edit your question to show us the code you have.

Comment: Include what version of SSAS and whether it's Multidimensional or Tabular

Answer (score 0):

This is a PowerShell error.
The line

$xmla = Get-Content $XmlaPath

depends on loading a value to the variable $XmlaPath, and I do not see it in the code. You never set a value for the variable, and Path parameter for Get-Content cmdlet is null.